# Gridstack widgets can't be moved after new widgets are added

Tags: javascript, redux, nvd3.js, ractivejs, gridstack

Application made with RactiveJS, Redux and Gridstack.

When new widgets are added, all is fine and widgets are movable/resizable as well. But when I delete all widgets and add, for example, two new, then:

1. widgets can't be moved and can't be resized. As in picture:
2. when try to delete widget it disappear, but other widgets change their position.

[image: You can see that right widget is moved to the right side, but handle stays where it is]

[jsFiddle is provided as follows](https://jsfiddle.net/buyrwacb/1/)

You can see that right widget is moved to the right side, but handle stays where it is. So **why is such behavior and how to deal with that**?

RactiveJS application have three components

```
DashboardComponent
WidgetGridComponent
WidgetComponent
```

Code provided as follows:

```
var Widget = Ractive.extend({
    isolated: false, // To pass events to WidgetGrid component (makeWidget, removeWidget, etc.)
    template: '#widgetTemplate',
    components: {},
    oninit: function() {
        // Load data to widget
    },
    oncomplete: function() {
        this.drawChart();
    },

    drawChart: function() {
        var self = this;

        function exampleData() {
            return [{
                    "label": "One",
                    "value": 29.765957771107
                },
                {
                    "label": "Two",
                    "value": 0
                },
                {
                    "label": "Three",
                    "value": 32.807804682612
                },
                {
                    "label": "Four",
                    "value": 196.45946739256
                },
                {
                    "label": "Five",
                    "value": 0.19434030906893
                },
                {
                    "label": "Six",
                    "value": 98.079782601442
                },
                {
                    "label": "Seven",
                    "value": 13.925743130903
                },
                {
                    "label": "Eight",
                    "value": 5.1387322875705
                }
            ];
        }
        nv.addGraph(function() {
            var chart = nv.models.pieChart()
                .x(function(d) {
                    return d.label
                })
                .y(function(d) {
                    return d.value
                })
                .showLabels(true);

            d3.select("#widget" + self.get("id") + " svg")
                .datum(exampleData())
                .transition().duration(350)
                .call(chart);

            return chart;
        });

    },

    data: function() {
        return {
            id: null,
            x: null,
            y: null,
            width: null,
            height: null,
        }
    }
});

var WidgetGrid = Ractive.extend({
    // isolated:false,
    // twoway:false,

    template: '#widgetGridTemplate',
    components: {
        Widget: Widget,
    },
    onrender: function() {
        // Init gridstack instance
        this.bindGridstack();
    },

    deleteWidget: function(id) {
        Action.deleteWidget(id);
    },

    removeWidget: function(id) {
        $(".grid-stack").data("gridstack").removeWidget("#widget" + id);
    },

    createWidget: function(id) {
        $(".grid-stack").data("gridstack").makeWidget("#widget" + id);
    },

    updateWidgetSize: function(id, width, height) {
        Action.updateWidgetSize(id, width, height);
    },
    updateWidgetPosition: function(id, x, y) {
        Action.updateWidgetPosition(id, x, y);
    },

    bindGridstack: function() {
        var self = this;
        var options = {
            animate: true,
            auto: false, // if false gridstack will not initialize existing items (default: true)
            float: true, // enable floating widgets (default: false)
            disableOneColumnMode: true,
            width: 10, //  amount of columns (default: 12)
            height: 10, // maximum rows amount. Default is 0 which means no maximum rows
            // height: 10,
            // cellHeight: 80,
            disableResize: false,
            disableDrag: false,
            verticalMargin: 0,
            resizable: {
                handles: 'se'
            }
        };
        var grid = $(".grid-stack").gridstack(options);

        // On user ends resizing
        grid.on('gsresizestop', function(event, elem) {
            var $el = $(elem);
            var node = $el.data('_gridstack_node');
            var id = node.el.attr("id").replace("widget", "");

            self.updateWidgetSize(id, node.width, node.height, node.el.css("width"), node.el.css("height"));
        });

        // On user ends dragging
        grid.on('dragstop', function(event, ui) {
            var $el = $(event.target);
            var node = $el.data('_gridstack_node');
            var id = $el.attr("id").replace("ar-widget", "");

            self.updateWidgetPosition(id, node.x, node.y);
        });
    },

    data: function() {
        return {
            widgets: [],
        }
    }
});

var Dashboard = Ractive.extend({
    el: '#dashboard', //document.body,
    template: '#dashboardTemplate',
    isolated: true,
    append: false,
    oninit: function() {
        this.on("add", function() {
            Action.addWidget()
        });
    },
    components: {
        WidgetGrid: WidgetGrid,
    },
    data: function() {
        return {
            store: {}
        }
    }
});
```

Answer (score 1):

There's several problems in there:

- `detach` is not called when unrendering a component. It's only called when `ractive.detach()` is called. Your grid was not aware of the widget's removal. After Ractive unrendered the widget elements, this caused the grid to act weird.
- On the flip side, `grid.removeWidget()` removes the widget from the DOM. After a state change, Ractive will still try to unrender. But since the element is no longer there and because Ractive wasn't aware of the widget's removal, it will cause a double removal.
- After a state change, the data for the widget is no longer present. `id` is already `undefined`. You can no longer use `id` when you handle `teardown`, `unrender` nor `destruct` events. You'll have to disconnect a widget from the grid earlier, preferably before the state change.

Ideally, you should just let Ractive do the rendering/unrendering of elements and only inform gridstack about making/disconnecting widgets from the grid. You're already doing this on render by using `makeWidget` instead of `addWidget`. For removal, you simply need to do the same thing. [`removeWidget`](https://github.com/troolee/gridstack.js/tree/develop/doc#removewidgetel-detachnode) accepts a second argument which, if `false`, will disassociate a widget from the grid but not remove the element from the DOM. This leaves unrendering to Ractive after the state change.

Here's an example: https://jsfiddle.net/fm133mk6/

Comment: Thanks for your answer! But your provided fiddle, have other issues :) I added three widgets, moved them around (some issues with moving too) then tried to remove them - first removed successfully, but others didn't. Can you please check your fiddle?